# php-fpm does not work me exec or shell_exec

Tags: php, unix, php-fpm, openbsd, exec

I have OpenBSD 5.6 and php-fpm, nginx.

Is chrooted by default on /var/www

I try:(test.php)

```
<?php
if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo "exec is enabled";
}else{
   // it's not
echo "exec is disabled";
}
echo "<br>";
if( ini_get('safe_mode') ){
   // safe mode is on
echo "safe_mode is enabled";
}else{
   // it's not
echo "safe_mode is disabled";
}
echo "<br>";
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

browser only prints:

```
exec is enabled 
safe_mode is disabled
```

I tried to change:

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

to

```
echo exec('/usr/bin/whoami');
```

but exec does not work

I've tried in the terminal;

```
# sudo -u www php-5.5 test.php
exec is enabled<br>safe_mode is disabled<br>www
```

So I think the whole problem is in php-fpm.

Would I could help?

Comment: We need your nginx and php-fpm config for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OpenBSD, and it's chrooted by default -- you said so yourself.

Commands such as `whoami` are not accessible by your PHP script. This is by design.

Comment: "commands outside the chroot are not accessible [...]" would be more accurate - you can always create a copy within the chroot, libraries too, or use a static binary.